# Spring Atwood Machine Analysis

Tags: lagrangian-formalism

I used Lagrangian mechanics for a Spring Atwood Machine as follows: [image]

My final answeres:

[image]

I know I did the math right but I am confused at the concept. Am I supposed to be left with two final equations for $\ddot x$ and $\ddot y$? Are these both equations of motion for the system? Can systems have two equations of motion? Do I need to go farther?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Am I supposed to be left with two final equations for $\ddot x$ and $\ddot y$

Well, I suppose it all depends on what you want to do with it.  These two equations are differential equations, so I would solve the differential equations so that you actually have equations for $x$ and $y$ as a function of time.  That's typically going to be more helpful to you than leaving it as differential equations.

> Can systems have two equations of motion?

Absolutely.  The system will be moving in two dimensions, so you need an equation of motion for the $x$-direction and the $y$-direction.

Comment: Like I understand how to do the math and everything, I just don't physically make the connection in my mind for x-direction and y-direction movement.